# CakePHP: Call to a member function

Tags: php, cakephp

I was developing a helper in CakePHP to upload files, but when i was using it on the action, it return a error.
I know what this error mean, i tried to call the helper with `public $helpers = array('Session', 'File', 'Html');` in the controller, but happen the same. I don't know what to do.
Error:

```
Fatal Error

Error: Call to a member function info() on a non-object 
File: /Users/diakonosdigital/Drive Diakonos/Google Drive/eJersusalem/WWW/ejerusalem/branches/app/Controller/DashboardController.php 
Line: 614
```

FileHelper.php:

```
        $info['name'] = $File['name'];
        $info['tmp'] = $File['tmp_name'];
        $info['ext']['mime'] = $File['type'];
        $info['ext']['ext'] = $typeq[1];
        $info['size']['b'] = $File['size'];
        $info['size']['kb'] = $File['size'] / 1024;
        $info['size']['mb'] = $info['size']['kb'] / 1024;
        $info['error'] = $File['error'];
        $info['hashed_name'] = $nname;
        if($getHashed):
            return $info['hashed_name'];
        else:
            return $info;
        endif;
    }else{
        return "A file was not specified.";
    }
}

/**
 * Função responsável pelo upload dos arquivos
 * @author Gabriel Cavalho
 * @param $File file required - Deve prover todos os índices que o campo 'file' oferece, tmp_name, name, etc.
 * @param $Options array required - Deve ser um array contendo as opçoes do upload, como o caminho de upload (path), se o nome deve ser 'hashed'
 */ 
public function upload($File, $Options){
    if(isset($File) && isset($Options)){
        if($Options['hash']){
            $File = $this->info($File);
        }
        if(empty($Options['path'])){
            $Options['path'] = WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS;
        }
        if($Options['hashname']){
            $File['name'] = $File['hashed_name'];
        }
        if($File['size']['mb'] > 5){
            $File['error'] = 5;
        }
        if($File['error'] == 0){
            /**
             * No caso de não haver erros nenhum, essa parte é entrada em ação. 
             */ 
            if(move_uploaded_file($File['tmp'], $Options['path'] . $File['name'])){
                return true;
            }else{
                return "An error has ocurred while uploading file.";
            }
        }else{
            switch ($File['error']) {
                case 1:
                    return "The file size exceeds the size provided by php.ini file";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    return "The file size exceeds the size provided by the form (MAX_FILE_SIZE)";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    return "The file wasn't fully uploaded";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    return "No file was uploaded";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    return "The file wasn't upload successfuly, the file size exceeds 5MB";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    return "Missing tmp folder";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    return "Failed in attempt to write file to disk";
                    break;
                default:
                    return "Failed to upload file";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }else{
        return "Please, provide valid \$File and \$Options";
    }
}
}
?>
```

The line that the error is:

```
$this->request->data['MainSlider']['slide'] = $this->File->info($this->data['MainSlider']['slide_file'], true);
```

Comment: Sorry, what's your actual question?

Comment: A Helper is one of the most wrong places to handle file uploads... This is a task for the model layer. Also there are already several plugins that handle file uploads and file management very well. https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage

Comment: @DavidYell What can i do to solve this problem

Comment: @GabrielOak how about adding the actual error message to your question...? As a developer you should know that "does not work" and not providing error messages or debug data is pointless. However, the Helper is overall wrong for what you want to do.

Comment: @burzum `Fatal Error

Error: Call to a member function info() on a non-object 
File: /Users/diakonosdigital/Drive Diakonos/Google Drive/eJersusalem/WWW/ejerusalem/branches/app/Controller/DashboardController.php 
Line: 614`

Comment: Gabriel where did you put your File helper?

Comment: Again: Wrong architecture, you're not supposed to call a Helper from a controller. There is a way to get the helper file into the controller but its plain wrong because it breaks the idea of the MVC pattern.

Comment: @AurimasLičkus `/app/View/Helper/FileHelper.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important thing is that you want to use **helper** as a **component**. Helper is meant to use only in views you can hack around and force to use it but, you must move your uploading logic to the behaviour. It's not view layer responsibility to handle uploads.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html which is accessible from the controllers.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html, for example file uploading: 
https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-FileUpload-Plugin/blob/master/models/behaviors/file_upload.php

So helper for view components for controller.

Comment: File uploading should be handled in the Model layer, which means a Behaviour. Not a component.

Comment: Yes i agree with you are right. Better place is Behavior. As it's data handling logic it should be moved there. Components is only for supporting Controller.